# How to reply to a message on a Discord channel with a bot in discord.py, when it is mentioned?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Quite stuck on this one - this is the code here:

No variations of ' if the bot is mentioned ' seem to work - any solutions?

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
       print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):

    # don't respond to ourselves
       if message.author == self.user:
          return
    
       if client.user.mentioned_in(message) and 'Hi' in message.content:
          await message.channel.send('_Solara hooman_ :wink:')

       else:
         return

client = MyClient()
```

Comment: This is why I don't use social media.

Comment: @stark  ?  - this is for a youth project if you were wondering :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `self.user` instead of `client`. This should work:

```py
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
       print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if self.user.mentioned_in(message) and 'Hi' in message.content:
            await message.channel.send('_Solara hooman_ :wink:')
        else:
            return
```

Now, if you ping the bot and say `Hi` (case-sensitive), it should respond.